# Title Toolbar уезжает из Toolbar при использовании DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, drawerlayout

С Linear,Frame и Relative лейаутами все работало. Но с DrawerLayout проблемы:

- заголовок тулбара уезжает из тулбара. При gravity:
  center_vertical | start - заголовок распологается по центру экрана, а
  не по центру тулбара. На скрине поставил gravity: top. Title выравнивается относительно корневого лейаута, а не относительно тулбара.
- перестал работать background для toolbar. Принимает цвет бекграунда общей темы приложения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**toolbar.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_action"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/toolbar"
android:gravity="top"
app:titleTextColor="@color/title">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/toolbar"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/drawer_menu_background"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java** - кусок где устанавливается toolbar

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_action);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.burger);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Корневой DrawerLayout в activity_main.xml должен содержать только 2 прямых потомка. Для решения проблемы нужно было объединить Toolbar и FrameLayout в один view. Я объединил их в vertical LinearLayout.